# Javascript get input element by name - from object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data object that contains names. These names are taken from tr object and need to filled inside form element. Now data object has exact names as input element are in selected form.

Now I want to iterate through object and find input element with that name and fill its value.

Here is code

```
<form id="newItems">
        <input class="form-control"  name="Name" placeholder="Enter name" type="text">
 <input class="form-control"  name="Price" placeholder="Enter price" type="text">
</form>

//Data Object
    var data = {
       Name : "name",
       Price : 50
    };

for(var key in data){
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log($('#'+modalId).find('input[name=key]'));return;
}
```

So far this return input element with name = key. But thats not what I need. I need whats inside key.

Comment: `$('#'+modalId).find('input[name='+key+']').val()` or `$('#'+modalId).find('input[name='+key+']')[0].value`

Comment: No that's not what I need. I will fill its value but first I need to check if that element is selected  and its not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed last `}` braces for loop. You put `key` as string it need to concadinate with `+` symbol like the below code.

```
 var data = {
       Name : "name",
       Price : 50
    };
var modalId ='hai';

for(var key in data){
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log($('#'+modalId).find('input[name='+key+']'));
    console.log($('#'+modalId).find('textarea[name='+key+']'));
    console.log($('#'+modalId).find('select[name='+key+']'));
   }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ureckd0/)

Comment: Yup that worked and I almost forgot to try such simple thing.  But thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Epistemologist - Glad it helps

Comment: One question though if I want to find form elements whether it is textarea or input or select how can I do that.

Comment: Need your html for this question

Comment: How can I get form element without mentioning its type. Whether it be input or textarea or whatever

Comment: Let me explain. I have form with input, textarea and select. Now I want to select form element based on name only. Now it could be textarea or select element. so if i could remove $('#'+modalId).find('[name='+key+']')  input from this query.

Comment: Well that is not very good solution. I know this would do the trick but there could many more elements.